# How do I modify a Jenkins plugin to stop it from putting a link on build pages?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to modify the existing [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin so that the `Environment Variables` link it puts on a build's page is hidden. If I'm understanding the Jenkins API correctly, I should be able to do this by finding where the `Action` interface is implemented and having `getIconFileName()` return `null`.

I found that method implemented in [EnvInjectAction.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/envinject-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/envinject/EnvInjectAction.java) and modified it to return `null`, but this had no effect--the link is still visible on build pages. I even tried modifying `getDisplayName()` and `getUrlName()` to also return `null`, but this also had no effect. Here is the modified method:

```
public String getIconFileName() {
        return null;
}
```

I've taken care to follow the instructions for [deploying a custom build of a core plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-Deployingacustombuildofacoreplugin) from the Jenkins plugin tutorial, and I've also tried rebooting the machine that Jenkins is running on, all to no avail.

I'm clearly missing something vital, but I can't figure out what it could be. What else do I need to do to make the plugin *not* display the Environment Variables link?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that? To hide sensitive information?

Are you aware of that even if you remove the link the variables can be displayed via:
`http://jenkins/job/YourJob/1/injectedEnvVars`?

Or according to the [EnvInjectPlugin-VariablesTraceability](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin#EnvInjectPlugin-VariablesTraceability):

*"You can also get build environment variables by the following

`HTTP GET URL: <jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/<build_number>/injectedEnvVars/export`"*

However, if it's just to remove the link and modifying the plugin is not a must add the following to Jenkins' `run/jenkins/war/css/style.css`:

```
a[href*='/injectedEnvVars'] {
  display: none;
}
```

Make a backup copy of the adapted `style.css` since it might get overwritten with a:

```
$ sudo service jenkins --full-restart
```

#### UPDATE

You can use a custom CSS with the following:

*Manage Jenkins* → Configure System → *Theme* → *URL of theme CSS*: `...`

Comment: Yes, to hide sensitive information. I have already removed the files that generate the `injectedEnvVars` page, so someone clicking the link will get a `404 Not Found`. Modifying the plugin is a must--we have multiple Jenkins servers and I'm not the person who updates them, so modifying actual Jenkins files would inevitably lead to the link coming back.

Comment: @khagler: What a pity. :-( I thought 50 sitting ducks caught with a three-liner. :-) I fear a cron job replacing the original with the backup regularily isn't an option either then, is it?

Comment: @khagler: Man! You can be picky! ;-) OK, last try before I dive into the plugin's source myself. What about a _Jenkins job_ that replaces...

Comment: I really am looking to modify the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As answer to overcome comment limitations.

I looked into the source of the plugin and I can say that I'd chosen `EnvInjectAction.java's` `getDisplayName()` to apply the changes, as well. Since it contains `return "Environment Variables";` and is the only file in the entire project that contains exactly that string.

I noticed that `EnvIinjectAction` is deprecated but that shouldn't do any harm anyway.

Have you tried to return an empty or an arbitrary string for testing rather than `null`. Maybe Jenkins itself doesn't like `null` being returned by this method. (But the next question is, why does it still display the original string of the plugin then.)

I even downloaded the jenkins-1.585 core sources and searched for invocations of `getDisplayName()` to check what is done with the value returned but there are 332 of them in `src/main/java.` I'm still trying to find the proper one.

Did you try the changed plugin on a local Jenkins on your machine? Maybe something went wrong while installing the plugin on the servers that are not maintained by yourself.

Have you considered [contacting the maintainer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) Gregory Boissinot?